# Laravel artisan right base_url

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel version 4.1.30. Where to tell Artisan the right base url?

My project is in a subfolder `http://localhost/test/`

When I use the browser the right base_urls are generated. I'm using the `route` helper function (but tried other also). However when I execute an artisan command base_urls are without the sub folder (just `http://localhost/`)

In /app/config/app.php the right base_url is used
`'url' => 'http://localhost/test/'`

From artisan if I call `\URL::to('/');` it returns `http://locahost`, instead of `http://localhost/test`

Please help.

Comment: Probably you have a local environment set and check if there is a `app/config/local/app.php` is available, if so then add the `'url' => 'http://localhost/test/'` in that file.

Comment: WereWolf: `app/config/local/app.php` is available of course (Tried also using live environment). If I use `Config::get('app.url');` it returns the correct url in artisan...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with Artisan?

Answer (score 0):

How do you detect your environment? If using Environment Variables, like `APP_ENV` set with Apache, try typing this in your terminal:

`export APP_ENV=local`

Comment: My problem is not with setting the enviroment, I need the right base url in artisan.

Comment: How many environment do you have? Can we see the app.php file for each of them? Check the terminal environment using `php artisan env`. Can we see your `bootstrap/start.php` file as well?

Comment: just simply install laravel 4.1 and modify app.url to an url which has sub directory like `http://localhost/test-sub-directory/`. Run artisan tinker and type URL::to('/') or try to call `route` function on a route alias. You can see that it will echo only `http://localhost/`, not the real base url.

Comment: Make sense, `/` is supposed to be the domain root. But why do you need to put a subfolder in there? Worst case scenario, just use `URL::to('/subfolder/');`

Comment: There are cases when only a subfolder is available for a site on a domain. I could use `Config::get('app.url')` from artisan, because it works as expected, but in my whole project I've used `route('example.alias')` which is working ok when http, but not in artisan. I just thought there's an alternative